# Zeep request leaves out attributes

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I've been trying to find an answer to this question, but with no luck so far.

I have a very specific problem.

I'm using Zeep to do a Soap request. And it seems like Zeep leaves out attributes that are required for the SOAP client.

Below is the XML request that Zeep is sending, and the problem start at employmentRatesReplace. This request gives med the validation error: ['Mandatory values [rate] missing in employmentRatesReplace section']

```
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:wsdlUpdateAgreementsV2 xmlns:ns0="uri:FlexForce">
      <apiKey>xxxxx</apiKey>
      <agreements>
        <UpdateAgreementV2>
          <extAgreementId>6005961001</extAgreementId>
          **<employmentRatesReplace>**
            <EmploymentRate>
              <fromDate>2023-08-29</fromDate>
              <rate>80.00</rate>
            </EmploymentRate>
            <EmploymentRate>
              <fromDate>2023-06-20</fromDate>
              <rate>70.00</rate>
            </EmploymentRate>
            <EmploymentRate>
              <fromDate>2023-06-19</fromDate>
              <rate>100.00</rate>
            </EmploymentRate>
          </employmentRatesReplace>
          <validationErrors/>
        </UpdateAgreementV2>
      </agreements>
    </ns0:wsdlUpdateAgreementsV2>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

However, when testing the request in SoapUI i can get it to work when adding attributes to the xml-tags. See below for a working request. Specifically "SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:EmploymentRate[1]" in the employmentRatesReplace tag is what makes this request to work.

```
 <soap-env:Body>
   <ns0:wsdlUpdateAgreementsV2 xmlns:ns0="uri:FlexForce">
       <apiKey>xxxx</apiKey>
       <agreements>
        <UpdateAgreementV2>
           <extAgreementId>6005961001</extAgreementId>
        ** <employmentRatesReplace SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:EmploymentRate[1]">**
                  <item xsi:type="tns:EmploymentRate">
                     <fromDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2023-08-16</fromDate>
                     <rate xsi:type="xsd:decimal">50.00</rate>
                  </item>
                  <item xsi:type="tns:EmploymentRate">
                     <fromDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2023-10-16</fromDate>
                     <rate xsi:type="xsd:decimal">60.00</rate>
                  </item>
               </employmentRatesReplace>
           <validationErrors/>
        </UpdateAgreementV2>
     </agreements>
    </ns0:wsdlUpdateAgreementsV2>
  </soap-env:Body>
 </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

WSDL is : https://rc.quinyx.com/FlexForceWebServices.php?wsdl